# Android: how can I prevent a drag from being interpreted as a long press

Tags: android, contextmenu, drag

When I inserted code to display a context menu it worked fine except that the menu appeared not only after a stationary long press but also (unwanted) at the end of a drag.

I have been able to prevent this by:  adding a ScrollInProgress flag to the View,  by checking this flag at the beginning of the onCreateContextMenu(...) method,  and if the flag is set by by-passing the code which adds items to the context menu.

However, I wonder if there is a simpler way of preventing the creation of a context menu when the screen is dragged.

Comment: We have no idea without seeing some code. Show us how you're detecting drags/long clicks.

Comment: In answer to Falmarri: I have defined a class MyGestureDetector which extends SimpleOnGestureListener; within this class the onScroll(...) method is overridden and that is where I set the scrollInProgress flag to true; in the app's main Actvity is the line `gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());`. That is how the start of a scroll (drag) is detected. The long press is detected simply by inserting the command `registerForContextMenu(myView);` in the main Activity's onCreate(...) and then writing code for `onCreateContextMenu` and `onContextItemSelected`.

Comment: Please let me know if I need to fill this description out at all.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, it isn't the gesture detector that's picking up the long press?
If it is, this can be disabled using setIsLongpressEnabled(boolean isLongpressEnabled)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I want the app to be able to detect a long press (and show a context menu) when a drag is not in progress. Do you mean that I should setIsLongpressEnabled to false in the onScroll method of MyGestureDetector (where I currently set my ScrollInProgress flag), and setIsLongpressEnabled to true when the end of the scroll has been detected?